# Axios | Can I make multiple POST requests in the same action?

Tags: post, axios

I'm trying to structure my backend properly and was wondering if I can make multiple POST requests (to different endpoints and with different data) to my API in the same action? If so, do I need to wrap the second `.post` in a `.then()`?

```js
export function signup({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log("signup function ran");
    axios
      .post("https://MYAPI.com/signup", { email, password }) //first POST
      .then(response =>
        dispatch({
          type: LOG_IN,
          payload: response.data.token
        })
      )
      .post("https://MYAPI.com/user", { data1, data2 }) // second POST
      .then(navigate("mainFlow"))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try it with async await syntax like this:

```js
export function signup({ email, password }) {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    console.log("signup function ran");

    try {
      const response1 = await axios.post("https://MYAPI.com/signup", {
        email,
        password
      });

      dispatch({
        type: LOG_IN,
        payload: response1.data.token
      });

      const response2 = await axios.post("https://MYAPI.com/user", {
        data1,
        data2
      });
      navigate("mainFlow");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I'll check that method next time I run into this. I ended up shoving the data into the single POST request and working it out on the backend. Thank you.

Comment: @mpc75 it would be better to check if it works before accepting as answer.